# Querying Windows event log using python + win32evtlog + timestamp filter in xpath doesn't return results correctly

Tags: python, xpath, pywin32

I'm trying to query Windows event logs (specifically the log created by Sysmon) using the following code:

```
SYSMON_XPATH_QUERY = """<QueryList><Query Id="0" Path="{event_log_path}"><Select Path="{event_log_path}">*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='{event_timestamp}']]]</Select></Query></QueryList>"""
SYSMON_EVENT_LOG_PATH = "Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational"
event_timestamp = "2017-06-25T17:13:00.453530200Z"  

while True:
    query_handle = win32evtlog.EvtQuery(
            SYSMON_EVENT_LOG_PATH,
            win32evtlog.EvtQueryForwardDirection,
            SYSMON_XPATH_QUERY.format(
                event_log_path=SYSMON_EVENT_LOG_PATH,
                event_timestamp=event_timestamp),
            None)
    event = win32evtlog.EvtNext(query_handle, 1, 1, 0)
    while event:
        # converting the event to xml and then python object -> result in sysmon_record
        ...
        event_timestamp = sysmon_record.TimeCreated # the same parameter I query on
        event = win32evtlog.EvtNext(...)
```

If I set event_timestamp to be about an hour before the current time, the query returns all events from that time up until the latest event, and then stops returning results. 
I thought it might be a problem in my conversion but then I tried setting event_timestamp to be half an hour before the current time and executing the script again, I didn't get any results.

Extra details:

- I built the XPATH query using Windows Event Viewer.
- When I execute the same query that doesn't return any results in a custom view filter in the Event Viewer I get the expected results.
- Python version: ActivePython 2.7.10.12
- Windows version: Windows 10 Pro

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
It seems that cleaning the event log before running my code solves the issue...
I'm not posting it as an answer because it's obviously isn't a solution. I'm not doing any more research because I don't mind cleaning the log (I don't care about past events).

Comment: I don't have the _Microsoft-Windows-Sysmon/Operational_ log (didn't research how to enable it). However If I change it to something that does exist (e.g. _System_) it seems to work OK. Could you post the complete code (the `...` parts)? I am assuming that for conversion you used `EvtRender` and then some _XML_ parsing code.

Comment: @CristiFati I actually found a way to circumnavigate the problem, I'm posting an edit but still leaving the question open because it's not a valid answer. The problem only reproduces when the log isn't cleaned before running my code (maybe too many events?).